# Как подготовить свой датасет для Machine Learning?

Tags: машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, dataset

*К примеру*: имеется папка с картинками **одного объекта**, формат картинок - png. Хочу научить классификатор (использую scikit-learn, Python) распозновать этот **объект**, но **что передать** в метод **fit** в качестве набора данных и меток для него, не знаю.

Помогите, пожалуйста, задаю вопрос уже второй раз, на прошлый ответ никто не дал. Очень нужно знать как это сделать.

*Точные вопросы*:

1. Как папку с картинками **объекта** превратить в набор данных с метками?
2. После выполнения первого пункта, как пользоваться набором данных и метками в самом коде? (По коду одной книги об ML после загрузки набора данных **MNIST**, он отображался в виде цифр, то-есть для каждого пикселя там было свое значение, но у меня есть только картинки в папке)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неточные ответы на "точные вопросы":

*1.Как папку с картинками объекта превратить в набор данных с метками?*

Превратить в набор данных с метками -  это означает разметить свои картинки.  Очевидно, вручную. Самому или нанять китайцев. Потом то что получится в результате подавать на вход вашей нейросети. Вид предаставления определяется инструментом, грубо говоря - той нейросетью, которую вы используете. Сие очевидно вы держите в секрете, по крайней мере -  нам не сообщили. А раз так -  смотрите документацию -  это все, что можно в таком случае посоветовать.  Там обычно и примеры есть. А в общем -  все должно выглядеть достаточно просто. Например, написать скрипт, который будет последовательно просматривать ваши папки с размеченными картинками, читать их в массив и передавать его (массив)  на вход вашей обучалке.

*2.После выполнения первого пункта, как пользоваться набором данных и метками в самом коде? (По коду одной книги об ML после загрузки набора данных MNIST, он отображался в виде цифр, то-есть для каждого пикселя там было свое значение, но у меня есть только картинки в папке)*

Странно, что после прочтении целой "одной книги по ML" (кстати, какой именно ?) Вы не поняли как работать с нейросетью. Вы что, из книги только код смотрели, а описание пропустили? Ведь то, что картинку надо предварительно оцифровать -  описывается даже не в книгах, а в любой статье по распознаванию картинок. И ваш MNIST прошел такую обработку до того, как попасть на вход нейросети. Ну а вам то-же самое надо сделать со своими картинками. А уж как- надо смотреть на ваши картинки: цветные они или чб, равноразмерные или нет и т.д.

А  в общем рекомендую книгу про ML все-таки "прочитать". Хотя-бы одну.

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо большое, ваш ответ действительно помог разобраться лучше. Книга называется "Прикладное машинное обучение со scikit-learn и tensorFlow" Орельен Жерон. А вообще я только на 3-ей главе "Классификация", в книге конечно было написано про то, что на вход всегда лучше скармливать цифры, но про метод оцифровки не видел ничего там, вот поэтому и спросил.

Comment: точнее вру, про метод оцифровки видел, но не в таком контексте, чтобы перевести картинку в массив значений пикселей